# '(' or '[' Expected

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting the following error when trying to compile my program.

'(' or '[' Expected.

```
 public AccountArrayList()
{
    // line one below is the hi-lighted code
    ArrayList accounts = new ArrayList;
    accounts.add("1");
    accounts.add("1");
    accounts.add("1");
    accounts.add("1");
    accounts.add("1");
    accounts.add("1");
    accounts.add("1");
    accounts.add("1");
    accounts.add(5,"900");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You know, if you're that beginner in the Java world, I strongly advice you to use a modern IDE (Eclipse, netBeans, IntelliJ IDEA), with all visual clues activated. This way, that kind of error will litteraly jump from the screen to devour your screaming eyes :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis on the constructor:

```
ArrayList accounts = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I kinda feel a little daft :P Though you can tell I am a learner. but again thanks, this place is a god send, and so are the people that contribute!

Answer (score 4):

Your constructor is wrong. It has to be;

```
ArrayList accounts = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 5 and higher, you will see that `ArrayList` uses [generics](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDMQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F1.5.0%2Fdocs%2Fguide%2Flanguage%2Fgenerics.html&ei=Mn_zTMuVHI2WOt-QwYsK&usg=AFQjCNGBWRhj5gqg_M2trdKbFZmhaoK7Qw&sig2=parS1X-GHmEBKujOZpcPOQ).

You can essentially to this:

```
ArrayList<String> accounts = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't construct an `ArrayList` like this.
Try

```
new ArrayList()
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

It's the call to the constructor that's the problem, it should be

```
ArrayList accounts = new ArrayList();
```

Also, you would do well to specify it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> accounts = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Because then the compiler will prevent you from adding Integers to it (for example) rather than Strings.