# Partial searching with an IF statement, syntax problems

Tags: java, if-statement

please bear with me as I'm rather new to programming.

I've created a simple application and I'm able to search a user via his name. I now want to be able to search via his number. I feel like I'm almost there but I've got the syntax wrong here, could anybody tell me how to resolve this? Wasted way too much time trying to resolve this! Eclipse is just giving me an error and say '( expected', and won't let me run the program.

So yeah basically I'm just looking for some advice on where I'm going wrong as I'm sure it's only a syntax error.

thanks in advance

here is my code:

```
 JButton searchForAUserBtn = new JButton( "search for a user" );
    searchForAUserBtn.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
        {   
                        if{Student con = user.SearchViaName( 
 nmField.getText());
                        if (con != null)
                            nmField.setText(contact.getNum());
                     }

                        else{Student con = user.searchViaNumber( 
 numField.getText());
                        if (con != null)
                            nmField.setText(contact.getNm());
                      }

                        }

        }
    });
    add( searchForAUserBtn );
```

Comment: You don't have any kind of condition after the first `if`.  You need to have a condition in parentheses every time you use the word `if`.

Comment: I basically want it to check if a user searches via name then do whats there, or if a user searches via number then run the second part of the code

Comment: How? @csmckelvey

Comment: Formatting your code would be the best place to start

Comment: What do you have to differentiate between searching by name vs number?  If you have a boolean, use that.  If you have different buttons, use different `ActionListener`s or check the contents of `ActionEvent e`

Comment: Different methods @phflack searchvianame is a method that does exactly that, and search vianumber searches by number

Comment: Yes, those are the divergent paths to output, that doesn't help figure out what the user is trying to search by to select one of those paths.  You have not explained your problem enough or posted enough code for somebody to answer you

Answer (score 1):

Your first if statement does not have a Boolean condition and it starts with a "{" when it should look like the if statements below it. The compiler is hitting "{" on the line with the bad if statement when it is expecting a "(" a Boolean statement and a closing ")". That is why you get the '( expected' error.

It should read like this:

```
if(Boolean)
{
    Student con = user.SearchViaName(nmField.getText());
}
```

Similar problem found on stack overflow:
['(' or '[' Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302659/or-expected)

This post may be closed by a moderator at some time because  it is a simple typographical error. Just FYI :)

Answer (score -1):

First off, this website is not for “how to Java” questions, so I recommend you go find some guides to learn what you’re doing wrong. However, because I’m feeling merciful, here is your answer:

```
//The problem is here.
if(/*Condition of some kind*/) {
    //Your code here
}
```

You need to actually have a condition after “IF”.

That is why Eclipse is giving you the “( expected” error.

Comment: Jacob, what do you think this code actually does?  I'm reasonably familiar with Java, and I can't understand what it might mean at all.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem oh hey I dont know but thats what his code said and if this is what he wants, then let him have it. I dont understand down votes for this 

Comment: I understand that the code isn’t legal, but his question was how to fix the “( expected” error that Eclipse was giving him. Nothing else.

Comment: How can you _possibly_ say you don't understand the down votes, when you've posted something that just isn't meaningful Java code?  Answers like this are what down votes were invented for.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem because I answered his question! If you think his question is bad, then downvote that instead! This whole website is a load of crap sometimes 

Comment: He asked about the error because he'd rather not have errors, not because he wanted someone to replace his error with a bunch of different errors.  His question is not great, but he's learning, and he's trying hard, so I didn't downvote it.  Your answer is just nonsense with no effort at all behind it.

Comment: But it’s the answer to his question!

Comment: It is no more an answer than "unplug your computer and the error will disappear from your screen".

Comment: Are you even reading his question? He asked HOW TO SOLVE THE ERROR HE WAS GETTING, which is what I did.

Comment: I edited it so it doesn’t have the nonsense that was in the condition statement. Happy now?

Comment: I am aware I need a condition of some kind I just don't know what condition to put to mean run this code if a user searches via name *_*

Comment: @J.Pavo well according to your question, thats not what you are asking. Please edit your question.